# can't use urdf.vcg file in urdf_tutorial

Tags: ros, urdf, roslaunch, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I type the roslaunch to try to run the package I create before, the terminal showed that:
ERROR: the config file '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_tutorials/urdf_tutorial/urdf.vcg' is a .vcg file, which is the old rviz config format.
I can't understand how to change the file, cause I didn't change the content of the urdf_tutorial since I downloaded from ROS. I have no idea about this....is there someone could help me, thanks so much for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120411/can%27t-use-urdf.vcg-file-in-urdf_tutorial/) by [saina110](https://answers.ros.org/users/11076/saina110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should update the launch file to use the urdf.rviz instead of the urdf.vcg

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saina110](https://answers.ros.org/users/11076/saina110/) on 2014-01-23**:
Thanks so much, I have done that and it works!